# tensorflow TFRecordWriter killing kernel

Tags: python, image, tensorflow, kernel

I am staring playing with tensorflow. I am facing the following problem. I am trying to run an example to do image recognition based on the Stanford Dog Dataset.I am stuck in the step of converting the image and label in TRFRECORDS files. 
In the image dataset folder there are 120 sub-folders, one for each breed (label).
If I run the code below with just on sub-folder in run fine (Actually I didn't tried to read the trfrecord file). But If I include a second sub-folder the process kills the python kernel process.

Here is the code I am running

```
import glob
import tensorflow as tf
from itertools import groupby
from collections import defaultdict

image_filenames = glob.glob(r'C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Tensorflow\images\n02*\*.jpg')

training_dataset = defaultdict(list)
testing_dataset = defaultdict(list)

# Split up the filename into its breed and corresponding filename. The breed is found by taking the directo
image_filename_with_breed =map(lambda filename: (filename.split("\\")[6], filename), image_filenames)

# Group each image by the breed which is the 0th element in the tuple returned above
for dog_breed, breed_images in groupby(image_filename_with_breed, lambda x: x[0]):
    # Enumerate each breed's image and send ~20% of the images to a testing set
    for i, breed_image in enumerate(breed_images):
        if i % 5 == 0:
            testing_dataset[dog_breed].append(breed_image[1])
        else:
            training_dataset[dog_breed].append(breed_image[1])

# Check that each breed includes at least 18% of the images for testing
breed_training_count = len(training_dataset[dog_breed])
breed_testing_count = len(testing_dataset[dog_breed])
assert round(breed_testing_count / (breed_training_count + breed_testing_count), 2) > 0.18,'Not enough testing data'

sess = tf.Session()

def write_records_file(dataset, record_location):
    """
    Fill a TFRecords file with the images found in `dataset` and include their category.
    Parameters
    ----------
    dataset : dict(list)
    Dictionary with each key being a label for the list of image filenames of its value.
    record_location : str
    Location to store the TFRecord output.
    """
    writer = None
    # Enumerating the dataset because the current index is used to breakup the files if they get over 100
    # images to avoid a slowdown in writing.
    current_index = 0
    for breed, images_filenames in dataset.items():
        for image_filename in images_filenames:
            print(image_filename)
            if current_index % 100 == 0:
                if writer:
                    writer.close()

                record_filename = "{record_location}-{current_index}.tfrecords".format(
                    record_location=record_location,
                    current_index=current_index)
                print(record_filename)
                writer = tf.python_io.TFRecordWriter(record_filename)
            current_index += 1

            image_file = tf.read_file(image_filename)
        # In ImageNet dogs, there are a few images which TensorFlow doesn't recognize as JPEGs. This
        # try/catch will ignore those images.
        try:
            image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(image_file)
        except:
            print(image_filename)
            continue

        # Converting to grayscale saves processing and memory but isn't required.
        grayscale_image = tf.image.rgb_to_grayscale(image)
        resized_image = tf.image.resize_images(grayscale_image, (250, 151))
        # tf.cast is used here because the resized images are floats but haven't been converted into
        # image floats where an RGB value is between [0,1).
        image_bytes = sess.run(tf.cast(resized_image, tf.uint8)).tobytes()
        # Instead of using the label as a string, it'd be more efficient to turn it into either an
        # integer index or a one-hot encoded rank one tensor.
        # https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-hot
        image_label = breed.encode("utf-8")
        example = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature={
                'label': tf.train.Feature(bytes_list=tf.train.BytesList(value=[image_label])),
                'image': tf.train.Feature(bytes_list=tf.train.BytesList(value=[image_bytes]))
                }))
        writer.write(example.SerializeToString())

        writer.close()

write_records_file(testing_dataset, r'C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Tensorflow\TRF\testing_images')
write_records_file(training_dataset, r'C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Tensorflow\TRF\training_images')
```

I monitored the memory usage and running the script does not seems to consume to much memory. I tried this in two Virtual Machines. One with Ubuntu and the other on with Windows 2000.

Does anyone have a idea?
Thanks!

Comment: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/using_your_own_dataset.md
Please take a look here!!

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. It was the *writer.close()* statement that was incorrectly idented. I should be idented in the first for loop but I idented it in the second loop.